# iOS disable push segue animation

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller

I have a storyboard with various segues for pushing ViewControllers in a NavigationController.

In storyboard i disabled Animation:

[image]

However the push is still animating. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That animation is the default behaviour. You need to create a custom UIStoryBoardSegue like so:

PushNoAnimationSegue.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PushNoAnimationSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

PushNoAnimationSegue.m is:

```
#import "PushNoAnimationSegue.h"

@implementation PushNoAnimationSegue

-(void) perform{
    [[[self sourceViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:[self   destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}

@end
```

For each segue now change the class to this one you just created and choose "custom" in the kind drop down menu.